# is it possible to set the default editor view for a pen in codepen

Tags: codepen

Is it possible to set the default view of an individual pen in codepen?

I am trying to set an individual pen to open in fullpage view as I have something taller than the bottom viewing are height to display.

If yes, where and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Had a response from codepen.io and that's a no...
So if you do want to do it, hack into their function for changing editor view via js onload.

D